# Correct way to check if ul have li element using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check if my `<ul>` has a `<li>` element in Jquery, if it does then it displays a div if not it hides it. So far I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#div-1 .div-2').each(function (index, item) {      
        var colorCount = $(item).find('.item ul li').length;
        $(item).attr('data', colorCount);
       if (colorCount > 0 ) {
            $('.colourClass').show();
        }
        else {
            $('.colourClass').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Is this correct or is there a stricter and better way to do it?

Comment: Can you show your HTML? Your display of `.colourClass` depends on very last `.item` status

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to use [toggle()](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function to achieve your requirements.

```js
const $ul = $('#test');
$('#div').toggle($ul.find('li').length > 0);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='test'>
<li>asdas</li>
</ul>

<div id='div' style='display: none;'>
 Show if li exist!
</div>
```

Comment: Even shorter: `$('#test li').length > 0`

Comment: Good catch @FedericoklezCulloca